# Deploying DHCP Role and Configure it in too many sites

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, dhcp, dhcp-server

What would be the best solution to automate building and configuring 60 DHCP Servers in different sites, that include configuring the scopes and all that stuff.

Comment: You could write a puppet module that configures a Windows DHCP server and then use Puppet to provision the sites or you could use a Linux DHCP server and use the puppet modules existing for those

Comment: There's no other way that can do so using the DHCP console, or any other Windows Server builtin tool?

Comment: You can probably do it via PowerShell but that is still a manual process unless you automate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running 2008 or 2008 R2? if you are running 2008R2 then Microsofts Desired State configuration (DSC) can be used to deploy and configure DHCP. It can be used to target multiple servers, think of it as Puppet but using PowerShell instead.

You can use DSC to deploy the DHCP role to you servers and then this DSC resource:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/xDhcpServer-PowerShell-f739cf90

Can be used to configure DHCP on the servers.

Here is and Overview of DSC

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/PowerShell/dsc/overview

you might need to upgrade the PowerShell version on your 2008 servers by installing the latest version of the Windows Management Framework

Answer (score 1):

Today in 2017, the best solution would be to use the [IPAM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831353(v=ws.11).aspx) feature available in Windows 2012 or 2016.

Comment: I don't think IPAM will let you deploy DHCP servers but it will let you manage them once they are discoverd

Comment: Correct, IPAM is for management not deployment. You can also use Server Manager MMC to deploy roles & features to multiple servers. Less overhead there if you do not have DSC servers setup and DSC clients configured to use it.